# Retrieve json file using Ember Data

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

I'm trying to retrieve some JSON content files using Ember Data, but it doesn't seem to be possible based on the convention of the library...

But, maybe I'm wrong.

I'm basically trying to retrieve my model "content" with the id "en":

`this.store.find('content', 'en');`

And I would like Ember Data to send the request to this URL:

`/content/en.json`

But it's trying using this url:

`/content/contents/en`

Is there a way to change the request path to what I need in the adapter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fully personalize your request with adapter.

Just make an `ApplicationAdapter` or a `ContentAdapter` which extends the RESTAdapter or any other default Adapter

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({

});
```

And modify the `buildURL` and `pathForType`

here is a link to the default implementation to buildURL https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.14.1/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L516

Im just confused about your URL however : it should be `/contents/en` by default and not `/content/contents/en`are yous ure you didn't add a `prefix`or a tricky `host`configuration.

with a default config the follow should do the trick for your case

```
App.ContentAdapter=DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
      buildURL : function(){
        var default=this._super();
        return default+".json";
      },
      pathForType : function(){
        return Ember.String.decamelize(type);
      }
});
```